# angularJS and JavaScript Math decimals issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue when doing calculation with javascript. As you can see in the fiddle, the answer show up rounded with no decimals and I dont understand why.

What do I need to do to show the decimals of $scope.total?

```js
var moment = angular.module('moment',[]);
moment.controller('momentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
  
  $scope.val1 = 96;
  
  $scope.val2 = 18;
  
  $scope.val3 = Math.PI;
  
  $scope.val4 = 13.5;
  

 $scope.total = parseInt( $scope.val1 ) + parseInt( $scope.val2 ) - parseInt( $scope.val3 ) - parseInt( $scope.val4 );
  
  
 
  
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="moment" ng-controller="momentCtrl">
Value = {{total}} <br>
Should be something like 97.3584
  </div>
```

Comment: You are using `parseInt`...

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` anyway?

Comment: It's not clear why you are using `parseInt` in your calculations.  Those are all numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `parseInt()` which removes the decimals, and since your scope variables are all already numbers, it doesn't actually contribute anything. If you're trying to make sure that the inputs are numbers, you can use `parseFloat()`.

For early input assurance in HTML5, you can use `<input type="number">`.  It stops a user from even attempting to put in a non-number, which is a good early catch (though you might *want* to allow invalid inputs, since you can then use JS to intelligently decide how to notify the user about what's wrong).

Comment: @ryanyuyu Great suggestion

Comment: Since you've integrated my comment into your answer (rather well I must say), I'm removing the now obsolete comment.  I've also made a few cosmetic fixes to your answer.  I'll delete this comment too in a few minutes.